# No attribute table or values in QGIS 3.2 Grass toolbox plugin output files

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

Using the Grass toolbox within QGIS 3.2 (and previously 3.0) when I import any files and overlay them, then use the "View Output" option (button), the resulting file has the correct polygon areas overlayed but with no attribute data/values, except for a "cat" column.

(this is a usual method that I have used hundreds of times successfully with QGIS 2.x)

NB: I have checked to make sure that the advanced "Do not create attribute table" option when importing the files is not checked.

Grass 7.4.1 is installed (and seems to be working fine in QGIS 2.18.21)

How do I ensure that an attribute table will be created when I import, overlay and export files from the Grass plugin within QGIS 3.x?